# Jquery link disable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have select element and a link button that on a link button click should be disabled and show element fieldset. Code can be seen. [here](https://jsfiddle.net/td1h9zub/) This is my script:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('#add').click(function(){

    //disable button on click
    if ($('#add').attr('disabled')) 
        $('#add').removeAttr('disabled');
    else 
        $('#add').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    //show/hide nytt Prosjekt
    $("#nyttProsjekt").toggle();
    if ($('#sign').text() == "-")
        $('#sign').text("+")
    else
        $('#sign').text("-");

    //toggle select disabled class and value
    $('#select').toggleClass( "disabled" );
    if ($('#select').attr('disabled')) 
        $('#select').removeAttr('disabled');
    else 
        $('#select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   });
});
```

on my html button looks like it is disabled, but when I click on it closes the open element, what I want is to disable button so that after clicking on it you can't click it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $("select") instead of $("#select")

#select searches for an id but there is no element where id="select".

### UPDATE:

`$('#add').one("click",function(){
....
});`

The .one attaches the handler to the click event for the link. The handler is only executed once.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/td1h9zub/3/)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't added that to jsfiddle, it is updated now, but that is not the issue here, I want the link button to be disabled, so that you are not able to click on it after first click, select works fine.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. You mean like this? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/td1h9zub/3/)